# Join two log files using aggregate filter of logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

I have used the below aggregate plugin for logstash to join two log files:
Log1:  PAGE,PAGEDESCRIPTION

Log 2: PAGE,HTTPAGENT

I WANT THE FINAL OUTPUT in kibana as: PAGE,PAGEDESCRIPTION,HTTPAGENT. The aggregate plugin snippet i used in filter

```
aggregate {
       task_id => "%{PAGE}"
       code => "
         map['PAGE'] ||= event.get('PAGE')
         map['PAGEDESCRIPTION'] ||= event.get('PAGEDESCRIPTION')
         map['HTTPAGENT'] ||= event.get('HTTPAGENT')
         #event.cancel()
       "
       push_previous_map_as_event => true
       timeout => 3

     }
```

But aggregate is not pushing the event to kibana ,  output in logstash conf file is as below:

```
output {

    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["10.0.62.184:9200"]
        index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"

        #document_id => "%{PAGE}"
        template_overwrite => true
    }
}
```

May i know what mistake i am doing or am i missing anything here

Comment: How are you starting logstash? Are you using `pipeline.workers: 1` if starting as a service or the option `-w 1` if starting in the cli? Update your question with real examples of the two events that should match.

Comment: The stack is Filebeat -> Logstash -> ElasticSearch -> Kibana

Comment: Logstash is started via filebeat, i have added beats.conf file inside /etc/logstash/conf.d/.beats.conf

Comment: Log1 :  PAGE,HTTPAGENT.    Log2 : PAGE,PAGEDESCRIPTION  what i want is :   PAGE,HTTPAGENT,PAGEDESCRIPTION.    After adding aggregate still in kibana i see two seperate events from two log files, third event which should be aggregated event i do not see after time out, aggregate snippet you can see above in the question, hope this info helps

Comment: By starting logstash I mean how are you **running** it. It is on Windows or Linux? Is it as a service or command line? Are you using only **one** worker on your pipeline? Also, share the two events that you are receiving in kibana, not only the fields names.

Comment: Logstash i have installed manually on ubuntu linux server using apt-get. I have just created beats.conf inside the conf directory of logstash, output of filebeat is pointing to logstash, filebeat is sending events to logstash from seperate file and output of logstash is to elastic search, i dont manually run the logstash script, neither via command line, only start filebeat and then the logs get parsed via logstash and goes to elastic search and then kibana

Comment: FYI.. The two events looks like as below:

Comment: "Google","Search Engine"   --- Log 1 Event.           "Google","Mozilla Http Agent"  ---- Log 2 Event.    These two events i see in kibana, but i dont see the aggregated event post timeout i.e.  "Google","Search Enginer","Mozilla Http Agent".  Hope you got all details now

Comment: Not using cli to start logstash, it gets started as a service on ubuntu, and filebeat sends log events to logstash

Comment: Please, **update** the question when adding more information instead of adding comments. If you are running as a **service**, then you need to look at your `pipelines.yml` inside `/etc/logstash` and see if the line `pipeline.workers: 1` is set for your pipeline, this is needed by the `aggregate` filter.

Comment: I have already set that to 1, still no combined event i can see